# Book for minimax bound proof?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

Can anyone provide me with a link or a book or steps to collect proofs for the upper bound, lower bound of a problem or how u come up with a formulation and prove it? I think my math foundation is not good but idk where to begin. The only thing of math proofing I had to learn was in secondary school. Smt like an equation is right with k, then prove it right with k+1. Or in university is NP hard. Which book i can begin with to learn with proof things? Thank you.